# Do I have to move hidden packages to project dependencies in a Haskell project just because I want to extract some functionality?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, extracting out some functionality involving a large monad transformer into a separate function requires me to declare a number of hidden packages as project dependencies.  This is a pain and takes time. Is there a better way of declaring the type of the extracted functionality, such that I don't have to add packages to my package.yaml dependencies?

Here is the sub-optimal workflow described in detail.

I have a Haskell persistent application that looks like this:

```
app :: IO ()
app = runStderrLoggingT $ withMySQLConn connectInfo $ runSqlConn $ do
  entries <- selectFirst [UserId ==. 0 ] []
  liftIO $ print entries
```

I want to extract out the sql connection so I can use it for other queries. So I make this function:

```
runDb = runStderrLoggingT . withMySQLConn connectInfo . runSqlConn
```

Now the compiler complains about ambiguous types in the `runDb` function:

```
• Ambiguous type variable ‘m0’ arising from a use of ‘runStderrLoggingT’
      prevents the constraint ‘(MonadIO m0)’ from being solved.
...
• Ambiguous type variable ‘m0’ arising from a use of ‘withMySQLConn’
      prevents the constraint ‘(unliftio-core-0.2.0.1:Control.Monad.IO.Unlift.MonadUnliftIO
                                  m0)’ from being solved.
```

So I comment out `runDb` fire up the REPL with `stack ghci` and query the type: `:t runStderrLoggingT . withMySQLConn connectInfo . runSqlConn`, to which ghci tells me:

```
runStderrLoggingT . withMySQLConn connectInfo . runSqlConn
  :: unliftio-core-0.2.0.1:Control.Monad.IO.Unlift.MonadUnliftIO m =>
     transformers-0.5.6.2:Control.Monad.Trans.Reader.ReaderT
       SqlBackend (LoggingT m) a
     -> m a
```

So I now write my runDb function with a type definition:

```
runDb :: MonadUnliftIO m => ReaderT SqlBackend (LoggingT m) a -> m a
runDb = runStderrLoggingT . withMySQLConn connectInfo . runSqlConn
```

But now stack complains that it cannot find type constructors `MonadUnliftIO`, `ReaderT`, and `LoggingT`. So I have to make sure I import them:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader (ReaderT)
import Control.Monad.IO.Unlift (MonadUnliftIO)
import Control.Monad.Logger    (LoggingT, runStderrLoggingT)
```

However, this doesn't work, since `Control.Monad.Trans.Reader` and `Control.Monad.IO.Unlift` are hidden packages.  So I have to add them to my `dependencies` in `package.yaml`, and now everything works.

Whew! This seems like a long process. Is there a better way of handling the ambiguous type problem that arose when I extracted the `runDb` function?

Comment: It... doesn't seem like that long of a process to me? Compared to, say, tracking down a stack overflow to the spot where I called `modify` instead of `modify'` or whatever, it's positively peanuts.

Comment: True, the process doesn't look long now that I know how I did it, but I also spent a lot of time frantically google and hoogling in the process of solving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ambiguity warning is probably caused by the [monomorphism restriction](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-930004.5.5). You could use `NoMonomorphismRestriction` or maybe changing from point-free to pointful style also helps, but I don't think these are good solutions.

You really should add type signatures to top level definitions like `runDb` and for that you will need to import the types that you use in that signature.

You can perhaps make the process slightly easier by using a type wildcard:

```hs
runDb :: _
runDb = runStderrLoggingT . withMySQLConn connectInfo . runSqlConn
```

Then GHC will give you the required type in an error message, so you won't need to use the repl.

You could even use [HLS](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-language-server/#haskell-language-server), which has suggestions that allow you to add the type signature and imports with a few clicks, but you will have to manually add the dependencies to the `package.yaml`.

I don't want to make light of your troubles, but I don't think this process should take more than about a minute and you will probably not need to do this very often, so I wouldn't worry about optimizing this workflow so much.

Comment: Thanks, the wildcard tip is very helpful.  I agree, I should always write a type signature. However, I didn't know in the beginning what the type was. There were too many monads stacked on top of one another for me to keep track of (sorry, I'm a beginner). I am also puzzled why ghci could tell me the type, but when stack tried to build the project, it complained about an ambiguous type.  Why could ghci tell me the type, while the compiler complained the type was ambiguous?

Comment: GHCi has the monomorphism restriction disabled by default because you usually don't want to add type signatures there.